# Filter data frame between 2 dates with format yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00

Tags: r

I try to filter a data frame table 1 between 2 dates with a fixed format YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00 according 2 dates got by a datarangeinput in Shiny with YYYY-MM-DD return format

I tried :

```
t1 <- as.Date("2011-03-01")
t2 <- as.Date("2011-04-01")
```

with table1

```
START_DATE_TIME 
2011-03-17 15:09:07
2011-03-18 15:09:07
2011-04-20 15:09:07

test <- ID_meas_limit[table1$START_DATE_TIME > t1 & table1$START_DATE_TIME < t2, ]
```

I don't know how to have same format to get the right result subset

Thank you

Comment: You can convert to Date class with `as.Date` i.e. `as.Date("2011-03-17 15:09:07")#[1] "2011-03-17"` i.e. `table1$START_DATE_TIME <- as.Date(table1$START_DATE_TIME)` and then do the filtering

Comment: Are the inputs form shiny characters or dates?

Comment: Values from Shiny are  input$daterange[1] and input$daterange[2] with a YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: What @amarchin is asking is the return value of `class(input$daterange)`.

Comment: Ok, class are date for input$daterange objects